# Implement Linked list where data is separate

Tags: c, linked-list

In C, can a Linked list be implemented and modified so that rather having the data stored within each node of the list, it is separated from the node. And a pointer within the node points to the data?

Comment: The sort answer: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried it with yourself, try it with your self and you will find that it is possible!!!

Comment: @piokuc Maybe a little too "sort" ;-)

Comment: @piokuc think it's spelled "short" :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Just instead of keeping keys in the nodes, you store pointers to keys:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_ListNode {
  struct s_ListNode *next;
  int *pointer;
} ListNode;

main() {
  int a = 3, b = 5;
  ListNode *root = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
  ListNode *tail = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
  ListNode *iter;
  root->next = tail;
  root->pointer = &a;
  tail->next = NULL;
  tail->pointer = &b;
  for(iter=root; iter!=NULL; iter=iter->next) {
    printf("%d\n", *iter->pointer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A. Yes, it is possible.
B. Why doing it ? the node is already a pointer by itself.